# matlab data to access database

Tags: database, matlab

### I want to export a data of exData variable (from MATLAB) to "DBS.accdb" Access 2007 database (table name: sayi, column name: toplam). I tried to run below codes. But they caused "invalid connection" error.

```
dataEx=sum_Up-sum_Down;
dbpath = ['C:\Users\t\Documents\DBS.accdb']; 
url = [['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ='] dbpath];
con = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver', url);     
colnames={'toplam'};
fastinsert(con,'sayi',colnames,dataEx);
```

---

Where is problem???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the database part but the quotes in the url look a bit fishy to me.
`['DSN='';']` will render as `DSN=';` since the inner quote is escaped, but I suspect it should be a double quote in which case you would need `['DSN='''';']`. So I would try:

```
url = [['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='''';DBQ='] dbpath];
```

Comment: First of all thanks for quick reply. I changed code. But it still make error like that:

Comment: Error using database/fastinsert (line 41)
Invalid connection.
Error in pc (line 152)
    fastinsert(con,'kisi_sayi',colnames,dataEx);

Comment: Sorry to hear that didn't help. What does `con` look like if you hover over it with the debugger? Does it give you any info on why the connection failed?